# AttributeError: 'TestAPI' object has no attribute 'test_1_get_all_providers'

Tags: python

```
import requests
import unittest


class TestAPI(unittest.TestCase):
    url = "https://192.168.100.11:30937/ehl/v1/cmgr/providers"


    def test_get_providers(self):
        response = requests.get(self.url)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        #self.assertEqual(len(response.json()), 1)
        print("Test1 1 completed")


    def test_get_machines(self):
        response = requests.get("https://192.168.100.11:30937/ehl/v1/cmgr/machines")
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        #self.assertEqual(len(response.json()), 1)
        print("Test 2 is completed")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    tester = TestAPI()

    tester.test_1_get_all_providers()
    tester.test_2_get_all_machines()
```

Comment: You are calling `tester.test_1_get_all_providers()` but your method name is `test_get_providers` - So its a typo ?

Comment: The error message is clear, `TestAPI` doesn't have `test_1_get_all_providers` and `test_2_get_all_machines`.